# Hide undock video button in Vivaldi

Tags: video, browser, vivaldi

How to hide the floating undock button on each video in Vivaldi? The button is inserted by Vavaldi in every video and allows to undock video from web-pages and watch it while browsing another tabs. I don't like it because this button rarely hides by itself like it supposed to do and just floats on top of videos like a noise. I don't need undock functionality whatsoever so I don't mind if this button will be disabled for good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Picture-in-Picture button, you can disable the "Picture-in-picture button on videos" setting in Settings > Webpages.

Comment: This isn't what OP was asking about. Good answers answer the questions that were asked.

Comment: I don’t know. The OP has very low rep; he might not know official terminology. The thing that the question discusses *sounds like* Picture-in-Picture.